# flex builder: how to populate an array from an external file of strings

Tags: apache-flex, arrays, builder, populate

hello i'm new to flex builder and trying to populate an array from an external file consisting of a list of strings.

how do i go about that? should i use some sort of a data object?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to get you started:

**Sample File** (file_with_strings.txt):

```
one, two, three
```

**Sample App**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    initialize="initializeHandler()">


    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            protected function initializeHandler():void
            {
                service.send();
            }

            protected function updateList(result:Object):void
            {
                var array:Array = result.split(/,\s+/);
                var collection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(array);
                list.dataProvider = collection;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:HTTPService id="service"
        url="file_with_strings.txt"
        resultFormat="text" result="updateList(event.result)"/>

    <mx:List id="list"/>

</mx:Application>
```

I would just use the [`HTTPService`](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/19/converting-xml-to-objects-using-the-flex-httpservice-mxml-tag/) class to load your external file.  You can change the `resultFormat` to XML, Object, and a few other things if you'd like.  Then just customize that `updateList()` method however.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: The list of strings is actually available. Just need to parse it and add each string to the array. Is there a command that does this or do I need to write the parser and the loop that will do this?

Comment: do you have a sample string? if you already have a string in the application, you'll have to write a parser.  I assumed the strings were comma separated.